# Removing P:confirmDialog using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I have created an confirm dialog using primefaces and the coding is below.

```
<p:confirmDialog id="exportDialog" styleClass="export-dialog" rendered="#{Controller.renderExport == true}"
    visible="#{Controller.renderExport == true}" header="Export" message="Do you want to export data ?"
    closable="false">
    <h:commandLink onclick="return closedialog()" value="Export All" action="#{Controller.exportAll}" " styleClass="export"/>
</<p:confirmDialog>
```

when I click the button inside dialog the dialog, it should close the dialog and an excel file excel needs to be downloaded.

To close the dialog i am calling the `closedialog()` function. the close dialog function is as below.

```
function closedialog(){         
    $("#exportDialog").remove();
    $("#exportDialog_modal").remove();
}
```

the dialog box got disappeared but i am unable to click the `textbox` behind the popup. but i am able to click buttons. am I doing anything wrong please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign a 'widgetVar' to your `<p:confirmDialog` like this:

`<p:confirmDialog  widgetVar="myConfirm"....`

Then to close it use the `hide()` command in your js code like this: `myConfirm.hide()`

I took a deeper look at your question,

You need to replace the

`onclick="return closedialog()"`

with

`onclick="myConfirm.hide(); return false;"`

The purpose of the `return false;` is to prevent form submition

Comment: Does it work with primefaces 3.5 ? Because i tried this it doesn't worked. I tried like $("#myConfirm").hide();

Comment: Yes, works on 3.5, use `myConfirm.hide()` no need to involve the jquery selectors in here its a primefaces api

Comment: javascript error like "TypeError: a[h].refresh is not a function" is thrown and the page refreshes when i click to open the popup.